# Service is not running when OS is upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10

Tags: service, windows-10

We have upgraded windows from 8.1 to 10. 
Now in Windows 10 services installed by us are not running.
The same services are running properly if we install these services on Windows 8.1.

ON windows 10, we tried below things which didn't solve the problem.

1. services-> select service -> properties -> Set [Log on] as LOCAL SERVICE
2. Set full permission to "perticuler" user or "everyone" user for the folder where service files exist.
3. Change owner of folder as "everyone", "system" or "perticuler" user where service files exist.

Below is a workaround which works but not feasible for us since it requires password and actually we want to know the actual reason behind this problem.

workaround :
1. services-> select service -> properties -> Set [Log on] as "This account" where user can be selected and it also requires password. Refer attached image.

Please note that the service is a dot net(c#) service and it runs internally a jar file. if it is able to run jar file then only service starts successfully.

[image: Workng method]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause and solution.

[Cause of problem]

Service unable to understand that, to run JAR file, which program should be run.

[Detail]

I tried to debug the code.
At the location where process is started, popup message like shown in below image is occurred.

location : processSample.Start()
[image]

- It means that atleast once user need to select the program.
- If we select [Java(TM) Platform SE binary] once, then after that the
  service always runs successfully.
- This behavior is in Windows 10 only.
- In addition to program selection, user setting shown in image in question is also required to run the service.
- I want to say that, in default program setting already correct program is selected for .jar files as shown in below image, but still windows 10 asks user to select program once.

[image]

[Solution]

Run JAR file from windows(c#) service with settings below :

```
sampleProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "javaw.exe";
sampleProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-jar Sample.jar";
sampleProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\SampleFolder";
sampleProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
sampleProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
sampleProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

Here working directory is the location where the [Sample.jar] does exist.
additinally a Path environment variable must be set in order to execure "javaw.exe".

Before fix I had implementation as below which is not proper for every system environment :

```
sampleProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Sample.jar";
sampleProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\SampleFolder";
sampleProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
sampleProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```